# Angular watch doesnt triggering when I change watcher modal inside $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I am calling a factory service to increment counter value, and when counter value is greater than 5 then I am calling again same factory service inside watch. I am using watch to see changed counter value.

My question is when counter becomes greater 5 it calls service but when again inside watch it calls factory service, it stops calling service, as per me it should go in infinite loop right? because when factory service is called the counter is still greater than 5.

Is watch stops checking value of modal when it is modified inside watch?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/g3t79jn8/) is the Fiddle

JS code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('testFactory', function(){
    return {
        incrementCount:function(a){
                       a++;
                       console.log('called service'+a)
                      return a;
        }
    }               
});


function HelloCtrl($scope, testFactory)
{
    $scope.counter = testFactory.incrementCount(5);
    $scope.$watch('counter', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if($scope.counter > 5){
            $scope.counter = testFactory.incrementCount($scope.counter);
        }
    });
}
```

html code

```
<div ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
    <p>{{counter}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: its working fine only. first time counter is 6. then watch will trigger again counter is 6. value is same so watch stopped

Comment: OK I have edited my question now inspite of passing 5 directly I am passing $scope,counter inside watch, now it is callinng exact 12 times then it stops.

Comment: same thing Am checking

Comment: I too surprise about it. its only calling 12 times

Comment: Thats what my question was :-), or modern browsers have become again smarter now ? :-)haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your condition `$scope.counter > 5 //  === false`

You can make it  `$scope.counter >= 5` or I suggest a new way to do that

[Check this link](http://jsfiddle.net/ewyak60w/1/)

Comment: I am amazed to see why the service is not calling infinitely when the condition is true, why watch is stopped watching $scope.counter? and it watches upto only 12 times. see my question once again please

Comment: that is normal because you pass the counter number by value not by reference

Comment: Then why it is calling 12 times only? either it should not call or should call infinitely. Check my updated fiddle n code and console.

Comment: the answer is the watch work fine but the $digest iterations reached to the maximum .

the here is the same code but on the plunker

[code example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ruq0RbYFVxRZHgWXBsdk?p=preview)  please see the console

that make the Fiddle has something that mute the angular Error at console

Comment: So basically you mean a digest loop can fire only 12 times?

Comment: no it means angular feel if he in infinity $digest it will break ,
it is not important how many times to feel that ;)

Comment: are you sure? then I think thats the problem then, what if I continuously want to loop or check my modal? angular digest can feel anytime not to watch it and will it stop?

Comment: check this link on angularJS web site
and that link come from your situation ( case )  at [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ruq0RbYFVxRZHgWXBsdk) dispay console and click on the erorr.

Comment: thank you boss, got the answer, actually angular digest loop checks for dirty check, if same values are repeating then it encounters it and stops it going in infinite loop, smart coding by angular. :-). I have upvoted too please write your comment in answer might help someone.